# Run multiple puppeteer at once

Tags: php, node.js, puppeteer

I have below script to open a page and take a screenshot.

```
 const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

    (async () => {
        const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ args: ['--no-sandbox', '--disable-setuid-sandbox'] });
        const page = await browser.newPage();


        await page.goto('https://example');
        const elems = await page.$('.thumbnail');

        await elems.screenshot({ path: 'thumbnail.png', type: 'png' });

        browser.close();

        await console.log("done");
      })();
```

I am running it via php exec command like below.

```
exec("node test.js ".$mainid." 2>&1", $out, $err);
print_r($out);
print_r($err);
```

Its working fine when I run the php script one time.But When I run same 
script simultaneously , One is stopping in middle and another one prints out error code **124**

I tried headless mode false , and browser.newPage("new context"); as mentioned in their github pages , still not working.

Comment: Running ports could be a issue?

Comment: no , I guess its closing current instance and opening new instance

Comment: Have you tried running via in multiple terminals rather than trying via php?

Comment: @Thamaraiselvam : yes working fine in two different terminals ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP will block the next execution until the current one finishes. That's why it's different from nodejs. Controlling nodejs from php will have it's own share of problems.

If you duplicate this line and run it, you'll see only one chrome, and the next one won't even execute if the current one doesn't close.

```
exec("node test.js ".$mainid." 2>&1", $out, $err); print_r($out); print_r($err);
exec("node test.js ".$mainid." 2>&1", $out, $err); print_r($out); print_r($err);
```

Usually it's not a good idea to use php for non-blocking app, it's just not the right tool for that, but if you still want to control and create non blocking app using php, you have to learn more about [PCNTL](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.pcntl.php) or [ReactPHP](https://reactphp.org/)

Answer (score 1):

I've used https://www.npmjs.com/package/concurrently to run multiple puppeteer scripts at once. You can see the command that I'm running here - https://github.com/Addstones/rpa/blob/master/package.json#L11

Comment: the link for the example is dead, can you add some example code?